# How to duplicate every element of a linked list recursively in Java?

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list

I have to write a duplicate function that duplicates every element of a linked list and returns a linked list such that if L = [2,3,4] then duplicate(L) = [2,2,3,3,4,4]. I have to do this recursively. I realize that below is not the correct solution, but I got confused. =(

```
   public class MyList {
     int value;
     MyList next;

     public static MyList duplicate(MyList L){
        if(L.next == null){
           L.next.value = L.value;
           L.next.next = null;
        } else {
           MyList temp = L.next;
           L.next.value = L.value;
           L.next.next = temp;
           duplicate(L.next);
        }
        return L;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why does your method not work? What does it do with your example input? Please don't suppose that we run your code and spend hours finding the bugs for you. Please help us a bit, provide as many information as possible. The general procedure should be to recursively walk down the whole list and then for each element insert the same element after the current one. Both parts should be relatively easy to implement. First you should implement a working **insert** method. Also, why are your list elements of type `MyList`? Shouldn't you have two classes `List` and `Element`?

Comment: If you keep on adding items to the list you  will never get to the end.   So instead work from the end of the list back to the beginning.  So I would create a double link list and add MyList previous.

Comment: Look i'm completely new to this and don't have a lot of practice with recursion or Java, you don't have to be rude. Glad it's easy for you to implement. I asked the question so somebody could explain it to me how to implement it.

Comment: Not meant to sound rude. Just some hints and tips. The thing is that StackOverflow has well defined requirements on the content of your question. When asking for help you need to provide a clear problem description, clearly show what you have tried so far to solve the problem on your own **and** show exactly where you are having trouble doing it by yourself, i.e. what specifically you don't understand. Unfortunately you just say *"I'm confused"* which doesn't help us understanding where exactly you have trouble ([help], [ask]).

Answer (score 0):

First, check that `L` isn't an empty list (`null`). If it contains a value, return a new list that has that value repeated twice, followed by duplicating the rest of the list.

By giving `MyList` a constructor, this is more readable.

```
public class MyList {
    int value;
    MyList next;

    public MyList(int value, MyList next) {
        this.value = value;
        this.next = next;
    }

    public static MyList duplicate(MyList list) {
        if (list == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return new MyList(list.value,
                     new MyList(list.value,
                       duplicate(list.next)));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You currently **add an item** and then **call the recursion on it**, ending at **endlessly adding items**.

You either need to at elements **behind** your recursion when processing in a forward-direction, or **after** the recursion when processing backwards.

---

Let's create a backwards-direction version. We first recursively walk to the end of the list and then resolve the recursion backwards, adding items **after** our current element each time.

```
public <E> void duplicateEntries(MyLinkedList<E> list) {
    // Do nothing if list is empty
    if (list.size() != 0) {
        // Call the recursive method on the head node
        duplicateEntriesHelper(list.head);
    }
}

public <E> void duplicateEntriesHelper(Node<E> node) {
    // Walk to the end of the list
    if (node.next != null) {
        duplicateEntriesHelper(node.next);
    }

    // Resolve recursion, duplicate current
    // entry by inserting it after the current element
    Node<E> duplicatedEntry = new Node<>();
    duplicatedEntry.data = node.data;

    // Insert element after current node
    duplicatedEntry.next = node.next;
    node.next = duplicatedEntry;
}
```

---

The classes I used should look similar to:

```
public class MyLinkedList<E> {
    public Node<E> head = null;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // Build something like "MyLinkedList[2, 3, 4]"
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("MyLinkedList[");

        StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(",");
        Node<E> node = head;
        while (node != null) {
            sj.add(node);
            node = node.next;
        }
        sb.append(sj);

        sb.append("]");
        return sb.toString();
    }
}

public class Node<E> {
    public Node next = null;
    public E data = null;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return E;
    }
}
```

And here is the demo:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Setup the list
    MyLinkedList<Integer> list = new MyLinkedList<>();

    Node<Integer> first = new Node<>();
    first.data = 2;
    Node<Integer> second = new Node<>();
    second.data = 3;
    Node<Integer> third = new Node<>();
    third.data = 4;

    list.head = data;
    first.next = second;
    second.next = third;

    // Demonstrate the method
    System.out.println("Before: " + list);
    duplicateEntries(list);
    System.out.println("After: " + list);
}
```

Of course you can add additional methods and functionality to them. For example using some **constructors** or **getter/setter** methods.